# WPF - Binding a Line with a converter that returns a Line

Tags: wpf

I'm attempting to draw some scatter charts with WPF, and struggling to draw the little tick marks usually present on chart axes. My view model defines the positions of the ticks using a `List<Tick>` for each axes, where each `Tick` item is just the cartesian coordinate of where the tick would fall on the axis. I have an `IMultiValueConverter` which uses the canvas size to convert the single point into a Line object that can be rendered... but how do I bind this? WPF wants me to specify X1, X2, Y1, and Y2, but I just want to give it the line.

My thought was to define a data template like the following, but it does not compile because I can't give `Line` a multibinding directly. Is there an intermediate element / attribute I could be using?

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:Tick}" x:Key="TickTemplate">
        <Line>
            <WhatsMissing?>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PointsConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Points"/>
                    <Binding Path="DataContext.MinPoint" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"/>
                    <Binding Path="DataContext.MaxPoint" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"/>
                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="ChartCanvas"/>
                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="ChartCanvas"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </WhatsMissing?>
        </Line>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind a ContentControl's `Content` property to the Line returned from you converter, but IMO a converter should not deal with UIElements. Creating and manipulating UIElements in code behind should generally be avoided.

Better return a [LineGeometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.linegeometry(v=vs.110).aspx) from your converter, and bind a Path's `Data` property to the result:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:Tick}" x:Key="TickTemplate">
    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Path.Data>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PointsConverter}">
                ...
            </MultiBinding>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</DataTemplate>
```